# Please help identify insect found indoor in Malaysia, south east Asia

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Found this insect in my home. About half an inch long. Would appreciate it if any of you could help me identify it. Thanks.

Comment: that's a cricket

Answer (score -1):

In the USA we call these insects `crickets`. Because they make a noise that sounds like the pronunciation of their name. This one looks like a male with two cerci.